# APC configuration on Ubuntu 10.4. Problem with apc.shm_size, apc.shm_segments and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, php5

I installed apc on my ubuntu 10.4 vps today using the following lines.

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

While everything works fine. I encounter problems configuring `APC`. I try to increase the allocated memory size. To my understanding I could do this either by increasing the amount of segments `apc.shm_segments` or `apc.shm_size`.

If I configure `apc.shm_segments` and restart/graceful the server `apc.php` still shows only one segment. In the apache error log I can find the line:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc.shm_segments setting ignored in MMAP mode in Unknown on line 0
```

How, would I make APC use apc.shm_segments?

Nevertheless, I'd prefer to use increase apc.shm_size to the 128M I configured as

```
kernel.shmmax = 134217728
```

However, everytime I configure `apc.shm_size` in `/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini` and restart/gracful apache. Apache does start but hangs. It does not serve any websites and a `apache2ctl stop` is not regarded anymore.

Has anyone experienced the same and/or knows why I can't change the shm_size default value?

Many thanks!

Comment: can you post the relevant config you are adding to your apache php config files

Comment: all i do is setting `apc.shm_size = xxM`, it doesn't matter which value even the `apc.shm_size = 30M` which is I believe the default value Apache stops working normally. My /etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini looks like 

`  extension=apc.so`
`  ;apc.shm_segments = 3`
`  ;apc.shm_size = 96M`

As soon as I uncomment `apc.shm_size` and try to restart the apache it hangs. `apc.shm_segments` is ignored.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this config and see if it works:

```
extension=apc.so

apc.enabled=1                  
apc.stat=1

apc.shm_segments=1                  
apc.shm_size=256M                  
apc.ttl=7200                        
apc.user_ttl=7200                  
apc.num_files_hint=10000
apc.max_file_size=5M            
apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/zero
apc.enable_cli=1
```

Comment: Found the culprit, `apc.shm_size` wants to be configured without the M in the size `apc.shm_size = 128` works like a charm. Some more info on the problem can be found [here](http://e-mats.org/2010/10/apc_mmap-mmap-failed-cannot-allocate-memory/). Many thanks!

Comment: sounds like you got an old version of APC then